# C# regex to match exact number (including integers and decimals)

Tags: c#, regex

#### Summary

I'm trying to use regex to match an exact number (i.e. the number as a human would understand it, not the digit itself) within a larger string. The number I'm trying to match will vary. It could be an integer or a decimal, and it could be a single digit or multiple digits.

#### Examples

- If trying to match the number 2, I want it to find the 2 in `x + 2 + 3` but not in `2.5`, `2.52` or `5.2` (because that's the digit 2, not the actual number 2).
- If trying to match the number 2.5, I want it to find the 2.5 in `x + 2.5 + 3` and `2.5`, but not `2.52` or `12.5`.

Note that 2 and 2.5 are just examples, I want this to work for any arbitrary positive number (if it works for negative numbers that's not a problem, but it's also not a requirement).

#### Initial attempt

I started with `(\bX\b)+` (where X will be the number I want to match), which works when X is 2.5 but not when X is 2. This is because it's using word breaks to identify the start and end of the number, but a decimal point counts as a word break. This means that if X is 2 (i.e. the regex is `(\b2\b)+`) it will match the number 2 (correct), but also `2.x` (incorrect) and `x.2` (also incorrect).

#### Current attempt

I've fixed the problem of `2.x` by changing the expression to `(\bX\b(?!\.))+`. This excludes numbers where X is followed by a decimal point, so if X is 2 it will match `2` (correct), will not match `2.x` (correct) but will still match `x.2` (incorrect). If X is a decimal number, this works correctly (so if X is 2.5 it will correctly match `2.5` and exclude `12.5` or `2.51`).

How can I avoid matching X when it's preceded by a decimal point?

#### Real use-case

If it helps, the end goal is to use this with the C# Regex.Replace function as follows:

```
private static string ReplaceNumberWithinFormula(string originalFormula, double numberToReplace, string textToReplaceNumberWith)
{
    return Regex.Replace(originalFormula, $@"(\b{numberToReplace}\b(?!\.))+", textToReplaceNumberWith);
}
```

Comment: Note that you will have to `Regex.Escape` the `numberToReplace` as it may contain `.`

Comment: Good spot, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Tim did you try the solution I posted. Can you tell me how it doesn't fit your requirement?

Comment: @Saksham There is no need to try that, Tim does not want to extract/remove *any* numbers, Tim wants to replace *specific* numbers passed to the `ReplaceNumberWithinFormula` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
private static string ReplaceNumberWithinFormula(string originalFormula, double numberToReplace, string textToReplaceNumberWith)
{
    return Regex.Replace(originalFormula, $@"(?<!\d\.?){Regex.Escape(numberToReplace.ToString())}(?!\.?\d)", textToReplaceNumberWith);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/NdoeYj)

The `(?<!\d\.?){Regex.Escape(numberToReplace.ToString())}(?!\.?\d)`, given the variable inside is equal to `2.5`, translates into `(?<!\d\.?)2\.5(?!\.?\d)` and matches `2.5` only if

- `(?<!\d\.?)` - not preceded with a digit and an optional `.`
- `(?!\.?\d)` - not followed with an optional `.` and then a digit.

See the [**regex demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cd%5c.%3f%292%5c.5%28%3f!%5c.%3f%5cd%29&i=x+%2b+2.5+%2b+3+%2b+2&r=XXX).

A simpler regex that will work *with the input like you have only* can be a word boundary + lookarounds based pattern like

```
private static string ReplaceNumberWithinFormula(string originalFormula, double numberToReplace, string textToReplaceNumberWith)
{
    return Regex.Replace(originalFormula, $@"\b(?<!\.){Regex.Escape(numberToReplace.ToString())}\b(?!\.)", textToReplaceNumberWith);
}
```

Here, the regex will look like `\b(?<!\.)2\.5\b(?!\.)` and will match a word boundary position first (with `\b`), then will make sure there is no `.` right before the location (with `(?<!\.)`), then will match `2.5`, assure there is no word char (letter, digit, or `_`) right after the number and then will check that there is no `.` after the number. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cw.%5d%292%28%3f!%5b%5cw.%5d%29&i=x+%2b+2.5+%2b+3+%2b+2&r=XXX).

It is equal to `$@"(?<![\w.]){Regex.Escape(numberToReplace.ToString())}(?![\w.])"`, and is more restrictive than **the top solution that will let you match the exact float or integer number in any context**.

Answer (score 0):

Add also a negative lookbehind:

```
((?<!\.)\b2\b(?!\.))+
```

Check the [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2PP7NI/1/).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?\b
```

- This matches whole numbers like 2
- Matches decimal numbers like 2.1
- Does not match patterns like 2. or .3

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think you've misunderstood the problem I'm trying to solve (sorry if my explanation was unclear, I struggled to articulate it!) At the time of using the regex, I will have a specific number I want to match, rather than trying to identify which parts of the string are numbers.

Comment: @Tim Alright, atleast it doesn't deserve a downvote.